# autofill each consecutive row with incremental value with respect to the first row

Tags: sql

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|1d   |name      |age | **teminal**   | 2000.00 |
| 501 | Muffy    | 24 | **gpi 01**    | 10000.00 |
| 502 | Komal    | 22 | **gpi 02**    | 4500.00 |
| 503 | Khilan   | 25 | **gpi 03**    | 1500.00 |
| 504 | kaushik  | 23 | **gpi 04**    | 2000.00 |
| 505 | Hardik   | 27 | **tally **    | 8500.00 |
| 506 | Chaitali | 25 | **punch **    | 6500.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

i would like a sql query for the terminal column to be inserted automatically with respect to the id column

Comment: No idea what you mean.

Comment: you need to explain more about the `terminal` column. Sample data and explanation doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: what you want? what is your problem?

Comment: downvote:
no code sample of what you tried + this is really not clear

Comment: i would like to update the TERMINAL column from ID 501 to 504 ,such that the column value gpi 01 to gpi 04 is incremented sequentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the terminal column to look like gpi 501, gpi 502 etc, after the insertion of the row, fetch the last inserted Id value. Then run an update statement where ID is so-and-so-value and update the Terminal field to gpi + id. Also you don't say which DBMS. In SQL Server 2005, the last inserted ID field is fetched with scope_identity().

In response to additional info given in your comments about use of Access 2013, here it is :

```
Update table_name set Terminal = 'gpi' + Mid(Cstr(Id), 2, Len(Cstr(Id))) Where Id In (501, 502, 503, 504)
```

Also, since you mention that the Id field contains values beginning with 5, like 501, 502 etc but the Terminal field should contain only two letters like 01, 02 etc, I have omitted the first digit of the Id field.

In future, you must give in your question, which specific database platform you are using, because SQL as a language is common to many platforms, MySql, Oracle, MS SQL Server, Access etc.

Comment: THANKS it working fine. how to get same result if the id column is 505,506,507,508. i.e. for id 505 terminal = gpi 01,for id 506 terminal = gpi 02, for id 507 terminal =gpi 03, for id 508 terminal = gpi 04

Comment: can we use some substraction query

Comment: It's already designed for that, if you want it to affect ALL records, remove the Where clause. if you want it to affect a subset of records give the list of Ids in the IN phrase of the Where clause. 
btw, if you original query has been answered, can you please accept the answer and mark the question as solved ?

Comment: If you do want something with subtraction, you should tell how many records you are looking at, and how many zeroes you need to pad it with.Just with the subtraction, without padding of zeroes, here it is : 
Update table_name set Terminal = 'gpi' + Cstr(Id - 500) Where ....

Comment: can u share how to pad the the output, Update table_name set Terminal = 'gpi' + Cstr(Id - 500) such that the  gpi 01,gpi 02 as so on to gpi 24                  rigth now i get the result as gpi 1, gpi 2 as on to gpi 24   please if u can help me with this last query for the statement

Comment: If the number of records are 24, no padding is required. My earlier answer will be good enough.  Ignore the subtraction-based answer. 
Update table_name set Terminal = 'gpi' + Mid(Cstr(Id), 2, Len(Cstr(Id))) Where Id >= 501 and Id <= 524

Comment: i required the padding of 0 for this query. Update table_name set Terminal = 'gpi' + Cstr(Id - 500). the result should be gpi 01,gpi 02,gpi 03 as so on to gpi 24.

Comment: Update table_name set Terminal =  'gpi' +   IIF(  Len(    Cstr(    Id     - 500)    ) = 1 , '0', '')   + Cstr(    Id     - 500)  Where Id >= 501 And Id <= 524

Comment: gr8 thanks, in the mean time i had used the below mention code to add a zero,  set Terminal_A = 'gpi'+right(' 00'+cstr(id-500) ,2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253761/how-to-join-the-result-of-two-statements-with-a-specific-order-by-caluse                                                            can u pls help me to correct the code for the above query